# Refresh to display content from Firebase + Angular 4

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I created a web app in angular 4 with data read from firebase (via angular fire 2), but on the pages where firebase data is displayed, I have to refresh the page once or twice before the data displays. This is not new data, its existing data. Also when I am writing data to firebase I have run the function twice from the front end before it actually writes anything. What could be the problem?

**Controller**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'

//import api service
import { FreeAgentApiService } from '../free-agent-api.service'

//import list item object
import { ListItem } from './listitem'

//import search componenet
import { SearchComponent } from '../search.component'

//import router 
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router'

//import animations
import { moveIn, fallIn, moveInLeft } from '../router.animations'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
  animations: [moveIn(), fallIn(), moveInLeft()],
  //host: {'[@moveIn]': ''}
})


export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  //user name
  name: any

  //state 
  state: string = ''

  //search string
  search: String;

  //declare filter
  filterOptions = ["Status: Active", "Status: Completed", "Status: Cancelled", "Status: Hidden"]
  filter = "Status: Active" 

  //projects array
  projects = [];

  //inject api service and router into component
  constructor(private freeAgentApi: FreeAgentApiService, private router: Router){

    this.freeAgentApi.afAuth.authState.subscribe( auth => {
      if(auth){
        this.name = auth
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    //init projects array on page load
    this.projects = this.freeAgentApi.getAllProjects()
    //console.log(this.projects)
  }

  //function to go to project
  openProject(projectName, projectUrl, projectEndDate, clientName){
    //router with parameters
    this.router.navigate(['project'], { 
      queryParams:  { projectName: projectName, projectUrl: projectUrl, projectEndDate: projectEndDate, clientName}
    })
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<!-- header section -->
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerItem">
        <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="../../assets/images/now-boarding-logo.svg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="headerItem">
        <my-search (onSearchChange)="search = $event"></my-search>
    </div>

    <div class="headerItem">    
        <a class="navTop">projects</a>
        <a class="navTop">reporting</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- main section -->
<div class="main" >
    <select class="statusfilter" [(ngModel)] = "filter">
        <option *ngFor="let f of filterOptions">{{f}}</option>
    </select>

    <div class="listentry"
         *ngFor="let p of projects | statusFilter: filter | searchPipe:'projectName':search"
         (click) = "openProject(p.projectName,p.projectUrl,p.endsOn, p.clientName)">

        <div class="listentryitem">
            <div class="userNameCircle">ML</div>
            <p class="project-title">{{p.projectName}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="listentryitem-2">
            <p class="note-grey">{{ p.clientName }} </p>
        </div>

        <div class="listentryitem-3"> 
            <input class="dateListItem field" type="text" value="{{p.endsOn | date: 'EEE d MMM'}}" disabled="true"/>
            <input class="budgetTimeInput" name="budgetTime" type="text" value="{{p.taskBudgetTime}}" disabled="true"> 
            <progress class="budgetProgressBar" value="{{p.totalTimeLogged}}" max="{{p.taskBudgetTime}}">
                {{ p.taskBudgetTime - p.totalTimeLogged }}
            </progress>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Provider for api calls**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//import http modules 
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

//import firebase modules
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

//import list item component
import { ListItem } from './dashboard/listitem'

//import project item object
import { ProjectItem } from './project/projectItem'

@Injectable()
export class FreeAgentApiService {

  //inject Http
  constructor(private http: Http, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public af: AngularFireDatabase) {

  }

  //function to populate authorization header
  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer 19wUDe8bnIsfuLsa1MhJfblztRj4WIZYCpnc_NQGG'); 
  }



  //project item
  //project = new ProjectItem()

  //array to store projects
  //projects = []

  //declare array to store tasks
  //tasks = []

  //decalare array of expenses
  //expenses = [];

  //declare total tracked time * hourly rate
  //totalTracked = 0

  //function to get all projects
  getAllProjects(): ListItem[]{

    let projects = []

    //declare headers
    let headers = new Headers();

    //add headers
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);

    //make api call and return promise array
    this.http.get('https://api.freeagent.com/v2/projects?sort=-updated_at&per_page=100', { headers: headers })
    .map((result: Response) => {

        //iterate projects list
        result.json().projects.forEach(element => {

          //varaible to hold single project
          let project = new ListItem();

          //assign values to list item object, named 'project' here
          project.projectName = element.name;
          project.status = element.status;
          project.endsOn = element.ends_on;
          project.clientUrl = element.contact; //use string to get client name
          project.projectUrl = element.url; //use string to get timeslipt

          //add current project to projects array
          projects.push(project);
        })
      })

      //get contacts
      .flatMap(() => this.http.get('https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts', {headers: headers}) )
      .map((res: Response) => res.json() )
      .subscribe( (res) => {

          //iterate projects array
          projects.forEach((project,index) => {
            //iterate contacts array
            res.contacts.forEach(r => {
              //match contact id with project
              if(project.clientUrl == r.url){
                //assign client name to organisation name
                project.clientName = r.organisation_name
              }
            })
          })
        })

        //get timeslips
      /*this.http.get('https://api.freeagent.com/v2/timeslips', {headers: headers })
      .map( (res: Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe((res) => {

        //iterate projects array
        projects.forEach(element => {
          element.timeLogged = 0
          //iterate timeslips
          res.timeslips.forEach(element2 => {
            //check if project url matches
            if(element2.project == element.projectUrl){
              //assign remaining time slip (increment)
              element.timeLogged += parseFloat(element2.hours)
            }
          })
        })
      })*/

      this.getFromFirebase(projects)
      return projects
  }

  //function to save projects to firebase
  getFromFirebase(projects: any[]){

     //get firebase list
    let storedProjects = this.af.list('/projects/')
    .subscribe((res) => {
      //console.log(res)
      //check if results array contains values
      if(res.length != 0){
        //iterate firebaselist
        projects.forEach(p => {
          //iterate projects arrays
          res.forEach( r => {
            //check if project is stored in firebase
            if(r.projectUrl == p.projectUrl){
              //assign time logged
              if(r.taskBudgetTime != undefined && r.taskBudgetTime != null) {
                 p.taskBudgetTime = r.taskBudgetTime
              }

              if(r.totalTimeLogged != undefined && r.totalTimeLogged != null){
                p.totalTimeLogged =  r.totalTimeLogged
              } 
            }
          })
        })
      }
    })

    return projects;
  }

  //function to sync firebase object with local object
  loadProjectToFromFireBase(project){
    //specify key, key is last four characters of url
    let key = project.projectUrl.substring(project.projectUrl.length - 4)

    //get firebase object, user project url as query parameter
    let currentProject = this.af.list('projects/', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'projectUrl',
        equalTo: project.projectUrl,
        limitToFirst: 1,
      }
    })
    .subscribe((res) => {
      //check if any fields are undefined and assign value
      for(let field in project){
        if(typeof project[field] == 'undefined'){
          console.log(field + " -> " + project[field])

          if(field == 'clientName'){
            project[field] = 'n/a'
          } else {
            project[field] = ''
          }
        }
      }

      console.log(project)
      //if no results are returned, write object to firebase
      if (res.length == 0){
        //write project object to firebase
        let ref = this.af.list(`projects/`)
        .update(key,project)

      } else {

        project.taskBudgetTime = 0
        //get expenses from firebase
        //iterate expenses array
        project.expenses.forEach(expense => {
          //init expense
          expense.expenseBudget = 0
          //iterate expenses array
          res[0].expenses.forEach(ex => {
            if(expense.url == ex.url){
              expense.expenseBudget = ex.expenseBudget
            }
          })
        })

        //get tasks from firebase
        //iterate project tasks array
        project.tasks.forEach(task => {
          //iterate results array and match task
          res[0].tasks.forEach(r => {
            //check if task exists
            if(task.url == r.url){
              //load task budget in time
              if(r.budgetTime != undefined && r.budgetTime != null){
                task.budgetTime = r.budgetTime
              }
            }
          })

          //incement billing rate * task budget time
          project.totalRateBudgetTime += Math.round(task.billing_rate * task.budgetTime)
          //incement total task budget time
          project.taskBudgetTime += Math.round(task.budgetTime)
        }
      )}

    })
  }

  //function to get tasks
  getTasks(projectUrl: string){

    let project = new ProjectItem()

    //declare headers
    let headers = new Headers()
    //add headers
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers)

    //get tasks from project
    this.http.get('https://api.freeagent.com/v2/tasks?project=' + projectUrl, {headers: headers })
    .map((res: Response) => {
      res.json().tasks.forEach(t => {
        //map to local variable
        if(t.is_billable){
          let task
          task = t
          project.tasks.push(task)
        }
      })
    })
    .flatMap( () => this.http.get('https://api.freeagent.com/v2/timeslips?project=' + projectUrl, {headers: headers }))
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((res) => {
      //init task budget time
      project.taskBudgetTime = 0

      //init total budget rate * total budget time
      project.totalRateBudgetTime = 0


      //iterate tasks array
      project.tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
        //add time logged field
        task.timeLogged = 0
        //load budget time from firebase or init to zero if not exists
        task.budgetTime = 0
        //iterate timeslips
        res.timeslips.forEach(timeslip => {
          //check if task url mathes
          if(task.url == timeslip.task){
            //increment time logged
            task.timeLogged += parseFloat(timeslip.hours)
          }
        })

        //increment total tracked time * task billing rate 
        project.totalTracked += Math.round(task.timeLogged * task.billing_rate)

        //increment total time logged for all tasks
        project.totalTimeLogged += Math.round(task.timeLogged)

      })
    })

    //console.log(project)
    return project 
  }

  //function to get bills (not expenses)
  getExpenses(projectUrl: string){

    //declare headers
    let headers = new Headers();

    //add headers
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers)

    //get expenses from project
    return this.http.get('https://api.freeagent.com/v2/bills?project=' + projectUrl, {headers: headers })
    .map((res) => res.json())

  }

  //function to get invoices
  getInvoices(projectUrl: string){

    //declare total invoices
    let invoiceTotal = 0;

    //declare headers
    let headers = new Headers();

    //add headers
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers)

    //get invoices from project
    return this.http.get('https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices?project=' + projectUrl, {headers: headers })
    .map((res) => res.json())
  }

  //funtion to get estimates
  getEstimates(projectUrl: string){

    //declare headers
    let headers = new Headers()
    //add headers
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers)

    //get approved estimates
    return this.http.get('https://api.freeagent.com/v2/estimates?project=' + projectUrl, {headers: headers})
    .map((res) => res.json())

  }

  //function to extract promise data
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();        
    return body;
  }

  //function to handle promise errors 
  private handleErrorPromise (error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  } 
}
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are expection an async resource to be synchronous. Basicallt this is what is happening:

```
getAllProject(){
    let projects = [];

    doAsyncStuffThatTakes30Seconds.subscribe(result => projects = result)

    return projects;
}
```

At the point where you return you projects, the async stuff hasn't completed. That's is why you are not seeing data. That probably makes you wonder why you do see data sometimes. That is because firebase caches the result until it has changed. So the async stuff is completed before the processing.

The solution would be to return an observable and do all the processing in the stream. Now you can subscribe in your component to get the data.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I have no clue how to structure the code. There is an http request getting info from the 'free agent api', I have to first return that info before making a call to firebase because the firebase info to be loaded is linked to that. How would I achieve that in an observable??

Comment: You can use `switchMap`for that. Eg: `http.get('someUrl1).switchMap(someValue => http.get(someValue))`